# getElementById --> getElementsByTagName --> outputHTML --> Перевернуть

Tags: javascript, html

Есть исходный код http://jsfiddle.net/wzwewr6d/1/

```js
var a = document.getElementById('file_estimates_rus'), 
    b = document.getElementById("file_theme_estimates_rus").getElementsByTagName("span");
for (var i=0; i < b.length; i++) { a.innerHTML += b[i].outerHTML; }
```

```html
<table border=1 cellpadding=10>
    <tr id="file_theme_estimates_rus">
        <td><span class="five">5</span></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><span class="two">2</span></td>
        <td><span class="three">3</span></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="file_estimates_rus"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

В итоге получается "5 2 3"

А что сделать, чтобы получалось "3 2 5", наоборот?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте обратный цикл:

```
for (var i = b.length; i-- ;) { a.innerHTML += b[i].outerHTML; }
```

**ДЕМО:** http://jsfiddle.net/wzwewr6d/2/

Comment: Если вы нажмёте на кнопку "фрагмент кода" (Ctrl+M) в редакторе, то получите окно как на JSFiddle, только на SO. Желательно пользоваться им, чтобы всё содержимое было на СО.

Comment: @Athari Я в курсе, спасибо. Я пользуюсь этим редактором в тех случаях, когда действительно важно показать итог выполнения программы. Здесь я просто привел пример обратного цикла. Нет нужды в отдельной демонстрации.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы рекомендовал использовать операцию с DOM элементами, вместо innerHTML+= т.к. изменении innerHTML удаляются все узлы, а потом создаются новые.

Обновленное решение, который предложил пользователь VisioN:

```
for (var i = b.length; i-- ;) { 
    a.appendChild(b[i].cloneNode(true));
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wzwewr6d/3/